# need help generating random characters for memory match game in C

Tags: c

I'm developing a console game in c :
I've writed functions to print the game map in console (memory match like),
in each space that should contain a letter has been replaced with "?" symbol.

know I managed to develop this functionality with this idea :

```
  rand()%26 + 65
```

as far as I know, the following command allows me to print a letter of the alphabet using **integers**.
**My problem** is to figure out how to generate random pairs of characters from the alphabet and place them in order to make a fully memory working game. 

I'm so confused about the processing development of this game and I don't where to look. **Someone has any ideas on how to do it**?

Comment: So you *really* need a permutation of `{a,a,b,b,c,c,...z,z}`. I'd look up the Fisher-Yates shuffle if I were you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that the *[rand()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/rand.3.html)* function is a *[pseudo random](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandomness)* number generator. Even when seeded with its companion function: *[srand()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/srand)*, it is not guaranteed to produce purely random numbers.  To use it successfully in the manner you have described, i.e. obtaining a list of unique values from some min to some max, it needs help...

Following are examples of companion functions that work in conjunction with the rand() pseudo-random generator to provide a list of values, guaranteed unique, between some min and some max:

Summary: `int random = (rand()/32767.0)*max;` will return a number no bigger than max which is then tested for value >= some min.

```
#include <stdlib.h> //defines rand(), srand() and RAND_MAX

int randomGenerator(int min, int max)
{
    int random, trying;
    srand(clock());//seed the rand() function before using it
                   //call frequency must be less than clock tick frequency
                   //or values will repeat. 
                   //  (problem with the word pseudo)
    trying = 1;    
    while(trying)
    {
        //random = (rand()/32767.0)*max;
        random = (rand()/(float)RAND_MAX)*(max+1);
        (random >= min) ? (trying = 0) : (trying = 1);
    }
    return random;
}
```

To obtain the complete list of unique values needed, keep a list  of previously obtained values (within 'A' to 'Z') and exclude them as they are returned until you have a sequenced through a unique set.  Perhaps something like this example:

```
BOOL filled(int *p, size_t size)
{
    int i;
    BOOL results = TRUE;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        if(p[i] == 0) 
        {
            results = FALSE;
        }
    }
    return results;

}
```

Example usage of both functions together:

```
int main(void)
{
    int result, i;
    int c='g';
    int previous['Z'-'A'+1] = {{0}}; //size array to contain alphbet, 
                                     //initialize all elements 
    size_t size = sizeof(previous)/sizeof(previous[0]);

    while(c != 'q')
    {
        while(!filled(previous, size))
        {
            result = randomGenerator('A', 'Z');
            if( previous[result - 'A'] != 1)
            {
                previous[result -'A'] = 1;
                printf("%c\n", result);
            }
            Sleep(1); // 1ms delay to avoid aliasing the clock() function
        }
        printf("finished!\n");
        printf("'q' to quit, any other key to continue\n");
        c = getchar();
        memset(previous, 0, size*sizeof(int)); 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a million!!!! my project is working flawlessly now! thanks for your help man.

Comment: @Hellno301 - Your welcome.   A quick note, the magic number: `32767.0` is a float representation of `RAND_MAX`, which should be defined in your `stdlib.h`.  As implemented in the code example, the value 32767 needs to be float to accommodate meaningful results from the integer division.  I have edited the example to show this.